# Looping through each NoteProperty in a custom object

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a `PSObject` in Powershell like this:

```
$NetworkInfo = New-Object PSObject
$NetworkInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value "10.10.8.11"
$NetworkInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value "255.255.255.0"
$NetworkInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value "10.10.8.254"
$NetworkInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Network -Value "10.10.8.0"
$NetworkInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name DNS1 -Value "10.10.10.200"
$NetworkInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name DNS2 -Value "10.10.10.201"

$NetworkInfo
```

I want to do a specific action for each NoteProperty in this PSObject, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  For example (even though I know it's the wrong way to do it) this code:

```
  ForEach ($noteProperty in $NetworkInfo) {
    Write-Host $noteProperty
  }
```

Only outputs the entire object as an array:

```
@{IPAddress=10.10.8.11; SubnetMask=255.255.255.0; Gateway=10.10.8.254; Network=10.10.8.0; DNS1=10.10.10.200; DNS2=10.10.10.201}
```

EDIT: Each `NoteProperty` is of the variable type `System.String` - if that's pertinent.

Am I creating the object incorrectly, or do I just not understand how to go through the object?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use Get-Member as mentioned by Mike; an alternative that keeps the order is to use the PSObject property that is present on all objects:

```
#View details for all properties on a specific object
$NetworkInfo.PSObject.Properties

#similar code to Mike's, working with name and value:
$NetworkInfo.PSObject.Properties | foreach-object {
    $name = $_.Name 
    $value = $_.value
    "$name = $value"
}
```

Comment: Is this for a specific version of PS?I have the following code and it only outputs the standard Properties, not the NoteProperties

    $currentReport = ConvertFrom-Json '{"Disabled":[{"vmDev02":["02/20/2019","02/21/2019"]},{"vmDev04":["03/01/2019","03/02/2019"]}]}'

    foreach($entry in $currentReport.Disabled.PSObject.Properties) {Write-Host "$($entry.Name) - $($entry.Value)"}


As opposed to the following which outputs both Properties and NoteProperties

    foreach($entry in $currentReport.Disabled) { $entry | Get-Member }

Comment: Hiyo!  I've never used PowerShell v1, but this works on v2 and onward.

That example is looking at the properties on `$currentReport.Disabled`, which is an array.  Here's another way you might do that:

```
foreach($entry in $currentReport.Disabled){
    foreach($property in $entry.psobject.properties) {
        "$($Property.Name) - $($Property.Value)"
    }
}
```

Basically:  Loop through the array, and then on each item, loop through the properties.

Cheers!

Comment: Just checking in here from 2022 saying that this still works in PowerShell v7! Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

This should get you what you need:

```
$NetworkInfo | get-member -type NoteProperty | foreach-object {
  $name=$_.Name ; 
  $value=$NetworkInfo."$($_.Name)"
  write-host "$name = $value"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ForEach ($noteProperty in $NetworkInfo.PSObject.Properties)
{
   Write-Host $noteProperty.Name
   Write-Host $noteProperty.Value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Short (even Faster) version:

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.foreach({"$($_.Name) = $($_.Value)"})
```

Output:

```
IPAddress = 10.10.8.11
SubnetMask = 255.255.255.0
Gateway = 10.10.8.254
Network = 10.10.8.0
DNS1 = 10.10.10.200
DNS2 = 10.10.10.201
```

Or another one:

```
$NetworkInfo.foreach({$_})
```

Will give you:

```
IPAddress  : 10.10.8.11
SubnetMask : 255.255.255.0
Gateway    : 10.10.8.254
Network    : 10.10.8.0
DNS1       : 10.10.10.200
DNS2       : 10.10.10.201
```

You can also select 1 property like:

```
$NetworkInfo.DNS1
```

Which will give you:

```
10.10.10.200
```

Or select all DNS entries:

```
$NetworkInfo.foreach({$_}) | Select-Object  DNS*
```

Result:

```
DNS1         DNS2
----         ----
10.10.10.200 10.10.10.201
```

Or if you wish:

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.where({$_.Name -like 'DNS*' }).Value
```

Will give:

```
10.10.10.200
10.10.10.201
```

Combining foreach and where:

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.where({$_.Name -like 'DNS*' }).foreach({
"$($_.Name) = $($_.Value)"})
```

Wil give:

```
DNS1 = 10.10.10.200
DNS2 = 10.10.10.201
```

Transform it into a 2 dimensional array:

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.where({$_.Name -like 'DNS*' }).foreach({
,(@([string]$_.Name, [string]$_.Value))})
```

Do NOT forget the "," in "{,"
Output:

```
DNS1
10.10.10.200
DNS2
10.10.10.201
```

Which is two dimensional

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.where({$_.Name -like 'DNS*' }).foreach({
,(@([string]$_.Name, [string]$_.Value)) })[0]
```

```
DNS1
10.10.10.200
```

And the following:

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.where({$_.Name -like 'DNS*' }).foreach({
,(@([string]$_.Name, [string]$_.Value)) })[0][0]
```

```
DNS1
```

And...

```
$NetworkInfo.psobject.properties.where({$_.Name -like 'DNS*' }).foreach({
,(@([string]$_.Name, [string]$_.Value)) })[0][1]
```

```
10.10.10.200
```